# Vista panorámica 360° android studio

Tags: java, android

Buenas tardes! Tengo un problema, quiero incorporar a mi proyecto `Android` una vista de imagenes en 360°. Sin embargo, he pasado por una odisea cada vez más difícil. actualmente me he acercado a la respuesta con `StreetViewPanoramaView` de `android`, pero yo necesito mostrar imágenes propias y me ha sido imposible.

En la documentación hay un ejemplo, pero solo para `javascript` (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple?hl=es-419) y yo la necesito para `android studio`, ¿alguien me puede apoyar?

De antemano, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: [aqui](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/streetview) hay ejemplos de la documentación oficial.

Comment: el problema es que necesito una imagen propia, y solo me permite con: panorama.setLocation(latitud, longitud)

Comment: tienes razón, no leí bien. [Mira aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22345293/4987172)

Comment: es muy bueno, el problema es que la imagen es tomada con cámara 360 en locaciones, por lo que en este caso no me funciona!

Comment: Rene, porque no agregas una respuesta en lugar de poner url con posibles respuestas.

Comment: o alguien sabe como implementar PanoramaGL en android studio? solo encuentro tutoriales en eclipse